# When subproject is a subtree merge, how do I revert a commit that came from the subtree remote?

Tags: git

I have a [**testcase shell script**](http://wuertele.com/sites/wuertele.com/files/test-subtree-revert.).  I want to **downgrade a sub-project**, but can't figure out how. Here's the story:

I created two repos, "**subproject**" and "**superproject**". I committed several versions of some files into subproject, giving them tags "v0", "v1", "v2"... etc. In superproject, I added subproject as a repo and merged it as a subtree:

```
git remote add subproject ../subproject
git fetch --tags subproject
git merge -s ours --no-commit v1
git read-tree --prefix=subproject/ -u v1
git commit -m "added subproject at v1"
```

Next I update the subproject to v3, and that goes well:

```
git merge -s subtree -X subtree=subproject v3
```

But then I realize I really want v2. I think what I need here is a rebase, but I'm not sure. Here's what I tried:

```
git checkout -b downgrade-subproject-to-v2
git rebase -s subtree -X subtree=subproject --onto v2 downgrade-subproject-to-v2
```

But I see the contents of the subproject get spoojed out all over my superproject's main directory!

So I did some reading and found some other ideas. This one did not work:

```
git revert --no-edit v3
```

It also spoojed files in my superproject, and complained about conflicts. This also did not work:

```
git merge -s subtree -X subtree=subproject v2
```

Obviously, v3 has already been merged, so merging v2 (an ancestor of v3) will have no effect.

The only thing I've found that results in a downgrade is this:

```
git diff v3 v2 --src-prefix=subproject/ --dst-prefix=subproject/ | patch -p0
```

But I don't like it, because it doesn't actually show proper ancestry in the commit DAG. It is just a brute-force rewriting of the tree. Also, it relies on the patch program to do "merging", which is not nearly as smart as git merging can do. If superproject made any changes to subproject before the downgrade, patch will not be as likely to resolve merge errors as git merge would be.

Is there a ***canonical*** way to revert a sub-project version using subtree merges?  If not, is there at least something ***better than diff|patch***?

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to create a reproduction script!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ultimately `git revert v3` in `superproject` fails because it does not account for the fact that `v3` is “behind” a subtree merge (thus the recorded pathnames differ in `N` and `v3`).

## Revert atop `superproject` history

With Git 1.7.5 you can use

```
git revert --strategy subtree -X subtree=subproject v3
```

in place of your `git diff | patch; commit` method. It will potentially make better use of the merge machinery. However, with either method, the new commit’s parent will be built on the history of `superproject` (which may not be what you really want).

Your `subproject` history looks like this:

```
     (v1) (v2) (v3)
     /    /    /
----o----o----o
```

Your `superproject` history looks this:

```
     (v1) (v2) (v3)
     /    /    /
----o----o----o
     \         \
  ----M---------N
```

Both methods create commit `O` with this history:

```
     (v1) (v2) (v3)
     /    /    /
----o----o----o
     \         \
  ----M---------N----O
```

---

## Revert atop `subproject` history

You might be happier with a commit built directly on top of `v3`. You could subtree merge such a commit into the `superproject` history like you do with any new `subproject` commit.

- In `subproject`: checkout `v3`, revert it (`R`), and tag the result (`revert-v3`)

  ```
  git checkout v3
  git revert HEAD
  git tag revert-v3
  git checkout -       # go back to wherever you originally were
  ```

  Resulting history:

  ```
       (v1) (v2) (v3) (revert-v3)
       /    /    /    /
  ----o----o----o----R
  ```
- In `superproject`: fetch the result, and use subtree merge (`P`) to incorporate it

  ```
  git fetch --tags subproject
  git merge -s subtree -X subtree=subproject revert-v3
  ```

  Resulting history:

  ```
       (v1) (v2) (v3) (revert-v3)
       /    /    /    /
  ----o----o----o----R
       \         \    \
    ----M---------N----P
  ```

If you do not want to have `revert-v3` in `subproject` itself (e.g. because `v3` is okay in the context of `subproject`, but is just not suitable for use in `superproject`), then you can do the work entirely in `superproject` at the cost of churning your working tree (switching back and forth between “unrelated” commits will effectively delete and restore all your working tree files, so the mtimes, inodes, etc. will have changed):

- In `superproject`: checkout `v3`, revert it, tag it, go back to previous checkout, subtree merge the new commit

  ```
  git status        # make sure to start with a clean index and working tree
  git checkout v3
  git revert HEAD
  git tag revert-v3
  git checkout -
  git merge -s subtree -X subtree=subproject revert-v3
  ```

The major difference is that the final `revert-v3` tag is only present in `superproject` in this second variation. The resulting history has the same structure and content as the first variation.

If you can not abide churning the working tree of either `subproject` or `superproject` and you do not want `revert-v3` in `subproject`, then you can use a temporary clone of `subproject` (in the clone: revert the commit, tag it; in the `superproject`: fetch the tag from the clone, and subtree merge it; then delete the temporary clone).

---

## `git subtree`

You may want to investigate apenwarr’s [`git subtree`](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree) command. Its support for subtree merges is a bit more streamlined (e.g. `git subtree pull -P prefix repository refspec`). Also, its `git subtree split` command may be of particular interest since it would let you transform the commit made from the result of your  `git diff new old | patch` (or `git revert --strategy`) into a commit that appears to have been made directly atop the subtree’s history.

`git subtree split --prefix=subproject/ --onto v1`<sup>1</sup> would take the “revert on top of `superproject`” history:

```
     (v1) (v2) (v3)
     /    /    /
----o----o----o
     \         \
  ----M---------N----R
```

and extract a `subproject`-only history like this:

```
     (v1) (v2) (v3)
     /    /    /
----o----o----o-----R'
```

where everything before `R'` is the original `subproject` history and `R'` is a version of `R` with only the content from `subproject/`.

This ability to “extract after the fact” means you can just work on the content itself in `superproject` without having to worry about whether the commits that touch `subproject/` might be candidates for sending “upstream” to the `subproject` repository.

<sup>1</sup>
You could leave off `--onto v1` if you used `git subtree add` to initially add the subtree<sup>2</sup>. It puts special text in the commit messages it generates so that it can identify the “subtree” bits of the history.

<sup>2</sup>
Or you could “convert to `git subtree`” with something like

```
git rm -rf subproject &&
git commit -m 'converting to subproject/ to "git subtree"' &&
git subtree add --prefix=subproject most-recent-subproject-commit
```

Comment: Chris, you are HIRED.  Your answer is such high quality that I feel like I just read a chapter in a textbook.  I'm still studying the ramifications of all this, but so far I've determined that both the superproject revert and the subproject reverts work well with the patches I need to merge.  I think I prefer the second form of subproject merge (keep reversion in superproject), but I'm still studying the ramifications.  I will also look at git subtree, but I think I don't need it yet.

Thank you!

Comment: Subtree will require that your entire team be competent in using it. Is it worth the risk of someone committing at the wrong level? Personally, I'm waiting until Git 1.9 or something like that when it's fully baked into the tool. Nevertheless, a wonderful write up.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using git submodules with the help of git slave would help. Alternatively, just use one repository and keep changes to the subproject in a separate branch or set of branches.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks adymitruk, I didn't know about git slave.  My preference is to stick to vanilla git since it takes less arm twisting to get my users to learn a new methodology if they don't feel like they have to learn a new tool.  If vanilla doesn't solve all my problems I'll give git slave a look!  I tried submodules, but since it requires more steps for the end users, I gave it up.

Comment: Same here. Perhaps once they get familiar with submodules, they can go faster if they want with git slave. Good comment.